# SQL to show current PTID and Next_PTID based on my example

Tags: sql

Can you please help me in writing a sql based on the example & expected result below.
[Example & Expected outcome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZa1W.png)

I tried below SQL but not able to receive the expected result.

```
select 
  a.TeamPlanningID,
  case when b.[Start Date] is not null and [End Date] is null then a.[PTID] END as [PTID]   
 ,case when b.[Start Date] is null and [End Date] is null then a.[PTID] END as Next_PTID    
from  
  [TableA] a 
inner join [TableB] c on a.ConsultantsRefDataIDs = b.ID
where a.TeamPlanningID = 36
```

Comment: Please do not post sample data as a picture but as a text. Better as a fiddle and do NOT forget to tag your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select TeamPlanningID, ConsultantsRefDataIDs, PTID, 
  lead(PTID) over (partition by TeamPlanningID order by ConsultantsRefDataIDs) as Next_PTID
from tableA
order by TeamPlanningID, ConsultantsRefDataIDs;
```

Comment: A code only answer is low value, please explain how it works, especially in the places that your solution differs from the code in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much, much appreciated ... It worked for me and joined both tables as per the expected output and requirement.